# Issue with newline in text - UITextView to sqlite, sqlite to JSON (via NSString), JSON to PHP

Tags: php, iphone, sqlite, uitextview, asihttprequest

I have a UITextView that ends up sending the text to a sqlite db on the iPhone.  Later on I will be querying this data from sqlite, putting it into a JSON string and sending it to a server (PHP/MySQL) from the iPhone using `ASIHTTPRequest` (using `ASIFormDataRequest` class).

There is a data condition where this send to PHP fails to decode properly (using `json_decode`).  The data condition seems to be where there's a newline in the text that was entered to sqlite via the UITextView.

**Things I've Tested:**

- Write out the same JSON string that I'm trying to send to the server to a text file on the iPhone.  Take that text, copy it into a web form (that I put together for this troubleshooting) that POSTs the data to the same PHP script that accepts the JSON from the iPhone.  This processes successfully (e.g. decodes and writes to the MySQL db).
- Write out the same JSON string that I'm trying to send to the server to the console (using `NSLog`).  Copy the text from the console and copy it into a web form that POSTs the data to the same PHP script that accepts the JSON from the iPhone.  This processes successfully (e.g. decodes and writes to the MySQL db).
- Remove the newline in the sqlite db, run the app and send the JSON to the server per design, no problem...it decodes and writes to the MySQL db.

I want to keep the newline in the text as that is what the user typed and what they will expect when they see the information on the server.  Not sure how to keep the newline and at the same time be able to send the data to the server without any issues.

Thanks,
Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you creating the JSON string?

The newline should be encoded in the JSON as two characters: \n

Comment: I have a method that queries the sqlite db and returns a `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary`'s (each dictionary is a row of field/values from the query result).  I send this `NSMutableArray` to another method that pieces together the JSON string from this `NSMutableArray`.  I am simply taking what ever is returned from the query, build the JSON and send it.

Comment: Do you mean you're constructing the JSON string yourself by hand? If so the problem is likely to be as mentioned in my answer, you need to encode the newline into a \n. You could instead consider using a framework like http://code.google.com/p/json-framework to generate the JSON, which will deal with the encoding issues. If that doesn't help, please add an example of the invalid JSON into your question.

Comment: Yes, by hand.  I will try out your recommendation with the json-framework.  Thanks!

Comment: As a follow up, I utilized the json-framework recommended and it handled my encoding issues with the newline.  Thanks again.